# Way to check is an user a document author?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, author

Hello Domino programmers!

I work on a lotus database + xpages and i ran into a following problem:

I have Authors and Readers fields on document and both can contain users and groups.
Both fields are set on XPage using NamePicker control.
When document is saved i would like to hide an "Edit" button when user doesn't have rights to do so.

Is there a way to just check on document, datasource or context - if current user is document author? Or i have to check it all way long, comparing Authors fields - multiple usernames and groups with current username?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the Java method `NotesContext.isDocEditable(document)` to check if user can edit the document.

In SSJS you can do this:

```
var ctx = com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent();
return ctx.isDocEditable(doc);
```

This method is also [available as an XSnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=determine-if-an-author-can-edit-a-document-alternative).