# Is there any Method which could determine if user has access to document?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Is there any Method which could determine if user has access to document, meaning, user (or user group) exists in any of the Readers or Authors fields?

Example:

1. we have User1
2. we have NotesDocument in DB with docUNID, which has Readers/Authors
   fields, but User1 (and any of his groups) are not present in these
   fields.

User1 performs var doc = database.getDocumentByUNID(docUNID).
Method getDocumentByUNID returns valid doc, but any Method like doc.getItemValueString() – returns empty values.

I see only manual method of deciding if user has access to document - take value of some standard field, like “form”, and if the value isEmpty() == true – user does not have access to the document.

**doc.getItemValueString(“form”).isEmpty() == true** – user has no access to document.

Comment: Does this answer work with readers fields too? Try it out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21854399/785061

Comment: Use *doc.getUniversalID()*. It should be empty if the user has no access to the document.

Comment: Per, yes, I saw that topic (BTW: also really useful method), but under Anonymous there are some issues with rights, I think...

Comment: Sven, thanks, yes, agree, checking doc.getUniversalID() for emptiness is more universal.

Comment: @SvenHasselbach - move that to an answer, so you get the recognition of Andrews acceptance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *doc.getUniversalID()*. It should be empty if the user has no access to the document.